# Directional derivative of $f(x,y ) = \frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}, (x,y)\neq (0,0)$ & otherwise $0$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, limits-without-lhopital

> Find the directional derivative of
>   $$
> f(x,y) := \begin{cases}
> \frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}, & \text{for } (x,y)\neq (0,0) \newline
> 0, & \text{otherwise.}
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   at $(0,0)$ in direction of vector $u=\langle \sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}\rangle$.

Since it is a piecewise defined function I want to make use of the formula:
$$
D_uf(x,y)
=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+hu_x,y+hu_y)-f(x,y)}{h},
$$
where $D_uf(x,y)$ is the directional derivative of $f$ in direction of vector $u=\langle u_x,u_y \rangle$ at $(x,y)$.

My only concern here is: **do I need to normalise the vector $u$ before applying this formula?**

For my question, is $u_x=u_y=\sqrt{2}$ or $u_x=u_y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ (obtained after normalising the vector $u$)?

Comment: Thanks @amd , done.

Answer (score 1):

You can even take the vector $\;\langle 1,1\rangle\;$ for an easier computation, it has same direction.
But if you do not normalize before, you have to divide by the norm of the vector after. The order doesn't play a role.